# Headless JDK7 for embedding

Tags: java, runtime, porting, headless

Where can I find the headless version of JDK7 for the linux-i586 architectures?

I couldn't find anything on Oracle's page, maybe I am just blind, or there is no such pre-compiled JDK...

The purpose is that I want to port the runtime library of the JDK to a operating system with a custom JVM, and I think this should be the one suiting best for my needs.

Comment: Are you sure you need a separate build for that? What exectly do you understand by "headless"? Since I don't think any GUI-dependent code will run if you don't explicitly call it.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html provides the JDK for every platform.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik with `headless` I mean that the GUI-dependent code is already not included. :) I would need this version to keep it as slim as possible. @LutzHorn no, not the headless version.

Comment: Then you're out of luck :( But I think Java 8 comes with several lightweight profiles. Also you should at least go for JRE instead of JDK.

Comment: What _exactly_ does "custom JVM" mean?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen actually a completely self implemented version of the virtual machine. If you are interested, we are planning to release it as GPL in the near future.

Comment: This sounds very interesting.  Do you have any blog posts or articles available?  In any way, you should be very careful with Oracle software licensing.  If you want to go GPL then look at OpenJDK or GNU Classpath.

Comment: There are no blog posts/articles yet, because we dont like to talk about unfinished things. You can contact me at lokoxe@gmail.com, then I can tell you a bit more about our project. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a special headless version of Java 7.  But you can easily tell ordinary Java to run in headless mode.  For example:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true com.acme.project.Main
```

For more information on headless Java, read this Oracle page:

- [Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)

---

> I would need this version to keep it as slim as possible.

Your only options would appear to be:

- Ask Oracle if they can provide you with a special build (for money!!!).
- Attempt to create your own stripped down build from the OpenJDK sources.

Beware that the Oracle binary distribution licence forbids you from distributing a JRE produced by "cutting down" a normal one.  I don't know if this applies to a JRE that you have built from source code.  Read the relevant license agreements *carefully*.

But my advice would be to just use a standard JRE installer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, this would avoid loading the part of the code that depends on native UI functions, but my actual purpose is to remove the overhead of a JDK with UI-sources. But OK, as it seems there is no other way. ;)